# VB.NET Selenium question about webdriverwait to wait for specific element been load by browser

Tags: vb.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have trying so hard to search how to wait for specific element been load to the browser.
However, most of code are in python and C#, I am trying to convert but still cannot.

1. I cannot find ExpectedConditions please let me know which reference I need to imports, because I keep looking for is expectedCondidtion in namespace still cannot find it.
2. Can anyone share a code or link that how to use webdriverwait? because I still cannot understand.
   I want to do is wait a element been load to the browser, and if element not in page will do something else.
   Now I using is try and catch but, sometime internet slow cannot really wait for page fully load, direct show the exception of elelment is not in page.

Code :

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), timeOut);
 WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("MainContent_lblLandmarkUPRN")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below function to wait until element is visible

```
 public static IWebElement WaitforElement(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeoutInSeconds = 5, bool checkIsVisible = false)
    {
        IWebElement element;
        driver.Sync();
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
        wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(StaleElementReferenceException));
        try
        {
            if (checkIsVisible)
            {
                element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(by));
                element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(by));
              }
            else
            {
                element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(by));
            }
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException) { element = null; }
        catch (WebDriverTimeoutException) { element = null; }
        catch (TimeoutException) { element = null; }
        catch (StaleElementReferenceException) { element = null; }return element;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try it. BTW where is the desired capacbility in OpenQA. Selenium name space?

Comment: namespace OpenQA.Selenium.Remote
{
  
    //     Class to Create the capabilities of the browser you require for OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver.
    //     If you wish to use default values use the static methods
    public class DesiredCapabilities : ICapabilities
    {
}

Comment: @BlueGene namespace OpenQA.Selenium.Remote

Comment: Thanks a lot. May I ask also where is Chrome Devtool? I want to using CDP command to emmulate the ip located timezone and Geo location. I looking so long